# Why can I start a slice past the end of a vector in Rust?

Tags: rust

Given `v = vec![1,2,3,4]`, why does `v[4..]` return an empty vector, but `v[5..]` panics, while both `v[4]` and `v[5]` panic? I suspect this has to do with the implementation of slicing without specifying either the start- or endpoint, but I couldn't find any information on this online.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is simply because [`std::ops::RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) is defined to be "bounded inclusively below".

A quick recap of all the plumbing: `v[4..]` desugars to [`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html) using `4..` (which parses as a [`std::ops::RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html)) as the parameter. [`std::ops::RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) implements [`std::slice::SliceIndex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html) and `Vec` has an [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E) for [`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html) for any parameter that implements [`std::slice::SliceIndex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html). So what you are looking at is a [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) being used to [`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html) the `Vec`.

[`std::ops::RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) is defined to always be inclusive on the lower bound. For example `[0..]` will include the first element of the thing being indexed. If (in your case) the `Vec` is empty, then `[0..]` will be the empty slice. Notice: if the lower bound wasn't inclusive, there would be no way to slice an empty `Vec` at all without causing a panic, which would be cumbersome.

A simple way to think about it is "where the fence-post is put".

A `v[0..]` in a `vec![0, 1, 2 ,3]` is

```
|  0    1    2    3   |
  ^
  |- You are slicing from here. This includes the
     entire `Vec` (even if it was empty)
```

In `v[4..]` it is

```
|  0    1    2    3   |
                    ^
                    |- You are slicing from here to the end of the Vector.
                       Which results in, well, nothing.
```

while a `v[5..]` would be

```
|  0    1    2    3   |
                        ^
                        |- Slicing from here to infinity is definitely
                           outside the `Vec` and, also, the
                           caller's fault, so panic!
```

and a `v[3..]` is

```
|  0    1    2    3   |
                ^
                |- slicing from here to the end results in `&[3]`
```

Comment: "there would be no way to slice an empty Vec at all without causing a panic, which would be cumbersome" By that reasoning, shouldn't indexing it also not panic?

Comment: In the end, this has been a conscious choice - but a choice nonetheless - by the designers.

Comment: I believe it's useful for patterns for searching the first known occurrence and slicing from there-on, such as `let idx = v.iter().position(|x| x == 5).unwrap_or(v.len()); let v = v[idx..];`. This code will never panic, even on an empty vector. Otherwise we'd need to do `.unwrap_or(v.len() - 1)`, which *could* panic if `v` was empty.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I guess that normal indexing of a vector could be thought of as starting at that "fence-post" and returning the first available element, except panicking if the end is reached. It makes sense why the behavior is not consistent, but it's still slightly annoying. My particular use case was that I knew a vector would have at least two elements, and I got a slice of every element beyond that, which, if the vector had exactly two elements, was just an empty vector.

Answer (score 4):

While the other answer explains how to understand and remember the indexing behavior implemented in Rust standard library, the real reason why it is the way it is has nothing to do with technical limitations. It comes down to the design decision made by the authors of Rust standard library.

> Given `v = vec![1,2,3,4]`, why does `v[4..]` return an empty vector, but `v[5..]` panics [..] ?

Because it was decided so. The code below that handles slice indexing ([full source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.52.0/library/core/src/slice/index.rs#L320-L326)) will panic if the start index is larger than the slice's length.

```
fn index(self, slice: &[T]) -> &[T] {
    if self.start > slice.len() {
        slice_start_index_len_fail(self.start, slice.len());
    }
    // SAFETY: `self` is checked to be valid and in bounds above.
    unsafe { &*self.get_unchecked(slice) }
}

fn slice_start_index_len_fail(index: usize, len: usize) -> ! {
    panic!("range start index {} out of range for slice of length {}", index, len);
}
```

How could it be implemented differently? I personally like how Python does it.

```py
v = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a = v[4]   # -> Raises an exception        - Similar to Rust's behavior (panic)
b = v[5]   # -> Same, raises an exception  - Also similar to Rust's

# (Equivalent to Rust's v[4..])
w = v[4:]  # -> Returns an empty list      - Similar to Rust's
x = v[5:]  # -> Also returns an empty list - Different from Rust's, which panics
```

Python's approach is not necessarily better than Rust's, because there's always a trade-off. Python's approach is more convenient (there's no need to check if a start index is not greater than the length), but if there's a bug, it's harder to find because it doesn't fail early.

Although Rust can technically follow Python's approach, its designers decided to fail early by panicking in order that a bug can be faster to find, but with a cost of some inconvenience (programmers need to ensure that a start index is not greater than the length).